# Vue, how to pass function in props in JSX render?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My components looks like:

`App.jsx`

```
import MyInput from './MyInput';

const onChangeHandler = (val) => {
    console.log(val);
};

export default {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyInput onChange={onChangeHandler} />
        );
    },
};
```

and `MyInput.jsx`

```
export default {
    props: {
        onChange: {
            type: Function,
        },
    },
    render() {
        // as Sphinx suggested it should be this.$props.onChange
        return (
            <input onChange={this.$props.onChange} />
        );
    },
};
```

But `this.onChange` is undefined:

[image]

How to properly use `this.onChange` prop in `MyInput` component?

### CodePen

Here you can find CodePen with implementation of my problem:
https://codepan.net/gist/13621e2b36ca077f9be7dd899e66c056

Comment: onChange is nested, wouldn't it be `this.props.onChange`? Admittedly it's been a while since I've worked with Vue.

Comment: @Ben I've tried it - the same results: `this.props is undefinded`

Comment: it should be `_this.$props`

Comment: To be clear: `this.$props.onChange`, `this.props.onChange`, `_this.$props.onChange` and `this.onChange` all of them failed.

Comment: what is the error for `_this.$props`? I created one demo below, it works fine. did you pass correct value like `<my-input :on-change="function(){}"></my-input>`?

Comment: If I simply change `this.onChange` to `_this.onChange` error will be `_this is not defined ` - nothing surprising here. At the top of my question I wrote an example how I pass function to prop: `<MyInput onChange={onChangeHandler} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't start your prop name with on. The 'on' prefix in reserved.

Credits to:
[nickmessing - see his answer](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/issues/42)

Answer (score 0):

Check [Vue API: instance property=$props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#vm-props), you should use
`_this.$props` like below demo:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('child', {
  props: {
    onChange: {
        type: Function,
        default: function () {console.log('default')}
    },
  },
  render: function (h) {
    let self = this
    return h('input', {
      on: {
        change: function (e) {
          var test;
          (test = self.$props).onChange(e)
        }
      }
    })
  }
})

Vue.component('container1', {
  render: function (h) {
    return h('child', {
      props: {
        onChange: this.printSome
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    printSome: function () {
      console.log('container 1 custom')
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('container2', {
  render: function (h) {
    return h('child', {
      props: {
        onChange: this.printSome
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    printSome: function () {
      console.log('container 2 custom')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Container 1</h3>
  <container1></container1>
  <h3>Container 2</h3>
  <container2></container2>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.$props.onChange` looks great. But the problem is that `this.$props.onChange` is still `undefined`. Can you update your answer to more accurately describe my example of usage `MyInput` in `App`? I can only use render functions - HTML from your last snippet is not applicable in my example.

Comment: @Everettss updated. I created two components=**container1/2** using `render()` function, then they will pass own custom function to `props =onChange`

Comment: I've tried to rewrite your example in JSX and without success. You can check this codepen with your example rewritten to JSX https://codepan.net/gist/0538859e1768bad79035703c4b588d4e